# How to set max width based on parent's width in Sass?

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I have a container(Buttons) that is resizable. There's 2 buttons inside, 1 with dynamic text.

in my scss, I want to check if the width of the container is < 200, then max width of dynamic-button is 135px, else max width of dynamic button is 200px.

```
Buttons {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: auto;
            text-align: center;
        }

Button {
        @include box-sizing;

        margin: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
        min-width: 60px;

        &.hot {
            margin-left: 9px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use an `@if`

Comment: @FortyTwo can you tell me how the condition would be written in sass for this case?

Comment: An `@if` in SCSS won't be able to tell you the 'current width' of a fluid item.  You'd need Javascript to do that.  The `@if` (like other SASS functions) is simply used to compile your CSS. It does nothing at runtime, so it won't know your fluid element's widths.  You can use Media queries, percents, viewport width (vw), or if it has to be 200 exactly you can use javascript in combination with classes to accomplish this. Personally i'd find out at what breakpoint you want the button to resize and write a media query, and forget about it's parent container.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience and what I understand in your questions you must use a media query, inside the class your class "Button"